# Android Headless Browsing through WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webdriver, headless-browser

I am trying to create an Android app for a Website, Which is not mine. But is a search engine for Restaurants. They have no API to work with. And i want to heedlessly browse their website and put the search query in the HTML Form and Click the Submit Button. And then Parse the Results and Use it with my Application Code. After doing loads of research here, i am finally asking for it. [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399055/android-web-scraping-with-a-headless-browser), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30113445/how-to-perform-a-button-click-inside-a-webview-android), [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905821/android-webview-compile-a-form-and-submit-with-javascript) and many more that i have looked so far. So all i know so far is if i want to do the same on Google.com i would write:

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
       //Load HTML
            myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('q') =" + "StackOverFlow" + "; document.getElementByName('btnK').click();");
        }
    });
```

In the above code i am trying to put the search term "StackOverFlow" and Click the Search Button. But its not working. Kindly Help me out in this code or either point me in the right direction.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Creating an application which retrieves data that is publicly available on a website is not stealing, I suppose. Just like a Facebook client, Youtube Client and Above all how does Google Work(Crawling through Websites).

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while, but for the sake of letting others know, webviews no longer use `loadUrl` to run Javascript. Try using `evaluateJavascript`.

Since you've also mentioned headless browsing, I would recommend overriding `shouldInterceptRequest` in your client to redirect all unnecessary files (such as css, images, and perhaps js depending on the site) to a blank inputstream

Answer (score 0):

```
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
```

after overriding onPageFinished method not before

Comment: You mean, without adding the webview to the visual tree (or whatever it is called, you know what I mean)? Is it efficient? The webview doesn't create visual elements in the background even though it is not part of the visual tree?