# Parse and execute HTML in Android

Tags: java, android, jsoup, html-parsing

I need to parse HTML elements from a webpage in Java, fill out a form and submit it to simulate a login.

I've been doing a little bit of research and here's what I did using the `jsoup` library.

However, after implementing this, I realized `jsoup` is only for parsing and can't perform button click, for example.

In this example, I need to perform a click on `submitButton` element.

```
try {
    Document htmlDoc = Jsoup.connect(MY_URL).get();
    Element loginForm = htmlDoc.getElementById("login-form");
    Element usernameField = loginForm.getElementById("username");
    Element passwordField = loginForm.getElementById("passwd");
    Element submitButton = loginForm.getElementById("submit");

    usernameField.val(username);
    passwordField.val(password);

    // I need to simulate `submitButton` click so I can login

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
}
```

Am I correct in my understanding that `jsoup` is not capable of doing this?

If so, is there a library for Android that can?

I understand there are many Java libraries but most can't work with Android (ex. HtmlUtil) due to `javax` limitation.

Comment: Do you want to emulate a browser or do you just want to post a form? Why would you need to parse the form at all? After all, you are extracting no information from the form in the code snippet you supplied.

Comment: I don't need to extract any info. All I need to do is verify if the provided username and password are valid. If I can simulate a click, i can verify if the provided id and password are valid or not. I know there are better methods to do this however I need to implement it this way temporarily

Comment: The approach heavily depends on the nature of the site you want to probe. If it returns an error (404, 403, 401 for example), you can just post a username and password and look at the response. See https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html for getting on the right track. If you search for HttpURLConnection and HTTP POST, you will get plenty of tutorials on how to POST form data to a URL.

Comment: You need to find the target link and parameters that needs to be passed. You don't need to parse the page.

Comment: I already have the target link and parameters. Based on the the answer given below (link), I tried however I am getting the following response: "The most recent request was denied because it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh the page and try again." when I do the post method

Comment: Also keep in mind: jsoup doesn't provide a JavaScript engine. Since you are on android I would recommend: use a WebView to call and render a website, the use JavaScript to modify/insert values/content and trigger the submission.

Comment: @FredericKlein so you are saying this is possible through `WebView` and `JavascriptInterface`? Do you have an example or a link I can look at? I know that we can call Java methods from HTML/Javascript if I modify the site however I am not looking for that solution. I want to perform a `Submit` button click on the site from Java

Comment: This looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905821/android-webview-compile-a-form-and-submit-with-javascript. Just test the functionality in you desktop browser's JavaScript console, then use the JavaScript code in your android WebView and pass the result from the form submission to a JavaScriptInterface, so you can react in your Java code.

Comment: This might work. I will test it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can view this link. Provides a good [answer](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/).

The steps should be the following:

1. Get to the login page
2. Parse the html using jsoup for username and password
3. Replace it with the actual username and password
4. Use an http POST to post the username and password form.

Comment: Looks promising. I will check it out. Thanks

Comment: I tried this example however even when I enter the wrong credentials, it returns a `200`. On a browser, it returns  `303` so something doesn't seem right

Comment: I even tried doing the same exact task using a chrome extension called `Postman` and that returns a `200` as well. I want to know when user doesn't enter the right password. `303` is the response I am looking for so I can differentiate between successful and fail login attempts

Comment: @th3pat3l Did that help you?

Comment: Unfortunately no it did not. I was very hopeful